# Passing Numeric Variable into Simple oracle query

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have table

TableA

```
ID    PRICE    DATE
123   200      01-SEP-2015
456   500      01-AUG-2015
```

In my query i want to show date when (date + X months)< sysdate else show null.
I have issue using variable in that query.

Forexample in record 1

(01-SEP-2015 + 3 months) = 01-DEC-2015 is not less than sysdate so, I don't want to show that date.

but on the other hand  for second record
(01-AUG-2015 + 3 months) = 01-NOV-2015 is less than sysdate so, I want to show that date.

```
declare
x number(5);
set x:=3;

select 
a.ID,
a.PRICE,
case when( ADD_MONTHS(a.DATE, x) < sysdate() )
   then a.DATE
else
    NULL
end as NEW_DATE
from TableA a;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put an ampersand (`&`) before the variable name to tell SQL*Plus to substitute in the value of the variable:

```
declare
x number(5);
set x:=3;

select a.ID,
       a.PRICE,
       case
         when ADD_MONTHS(a.DATE, &x) < sysdate then a.DATE
         else NULL
      end as NEW_DATE
  from TableA a;
```

Also, `DATE` is a data type in Oracle - don't use it as a column name. You *can* do that but it's going to cause problems down the line somewhere.

Best of luck.